# document.getElementById with php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

im coding cards with timers, i have my database and this save the hour and date. My problem here is at the moment to print the timers

this code with "demo" on each the fields with $row[0] will display a timer on the screen, but i need one time foreach of the cards, i dont  have any idea of how i can do this, my consult i very simple
$row[0]= ID, $row[1]= serial number, $row[2]= street, $row[3]=year, $row[4]=month, $row[5]=day, $row[6]=Hour, $row[7]=minutes, $row[8]=seconds

```
<?php
$date = $row[3] . "-" . $row[4] . "-" . $row[5];
              $time = $row[6] . ":" . $row[7] . "-" . $row[8];
              echo $date . " " . $time;
              $date_today = $date . ' ' . $time;
              ?>
              <script type="text/javascript">
                  var count_id = "<?php echo $date_today; ?>";
                  var countDownDate = new Date(count_id).getTime();

                  var x = setInterval(function(){
                  var now = new Date().getTime();
                  var distance = countDownDate - now;

                  var hours = Math.floor((distance%(1000*60*60*24))/(1000*60*60));
                  var minutes = Math.floor((distance%(1000*60*60))/(1000*60));
                  var seconds = Math.floor((distance%(1000*60))/1000);
                  
                  document.getElementById(<?php $row[0] ?>).innerHTML = hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

                  if(distance<0){
                      clearInterval(x);
                      document.getElementById(<?php $row[0] ?>).innerHTML="COMPLETO"
                  }
                  },1000);
                  </script>
                  <?php
                  echo '<p id="$row[0]" style="font-size:18px;"></p>'
                  ?>
```

im prety sure my issue is on the document.getELementById

o i forget to tell that im doing all this on PHP/apache2

Comment: You are probably missing quotes. Check out the HTML source of the page. Or look at the console for errors. Also, you should be escaping the values in case they themselves contain quotes.

Comment: i want to display the ID on this array (pos 0) so, this ID will give me the Timers in each card, but i dont have idea of how i should call the content of `$Row[0]`

Comment: and on the `<?php echo '<p id="$row[0]" style="font-size:18px;"></p>'` how i should display this part, i was thinking how i can do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i took the code and modified like @Gardener sugest

```
$date = $row[3] . "-" . $row[4] . "-" . $row[5];
              $time = $row[6] . ":" . $row[7] . "-" . $row[8];
              echo $date . " " . $time;
              $date_today = $date . ' ' . $time;
              ?>
              <script type="text/javascript">
                  var count_id = "<?php echo $date_today; ?>";
                  var countDownDate = new Date(count_id).getTime();

                  var x = setInterval(function(){
                  var now = new Date().getTime();
                  var distance = countDownDate - now;

                  var hours = Math.floor((distance%(1000*60*60*24))/(1000*60*60));
                  var minutes = Math.floor((distance%(1000*60*60))/(1000*60));
                  var seconds = Math.floor((distance%(1000*60))/1000);
                  
                  document.getElementById('<?= $row[0]; ?>').innerHTML = hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

                  if(distance<0){
                      clearInterval(x);
                      document.getElementById('<?= $row[0]; ?>').innerHTML="COMPLETO"
                  }
                  },1000);
                  </script>
                  <?php
                  echo '<p id="' . $row[0] . '" style="font-size:18px;"></p>'
                  ?>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text"><?php echo $row[1]; ?></p>
              <p class="card-text"><?php echo $row[2]; ?></p>  
            </div>
```

Comment: How is this line working? `document.getElementById(<?= $row[0]; ?>).innerHTML` ? Shouldn't it be `document.getElementById("<?= $row[0]; ?>").innerHTML`

Comment: Sorry, my bad, i fixed that part, but yea, actually is how you say